# Unity3d application as user control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, unity-game-engine

Is it possible use Unity3d app written on C# as part of another WPF or winforms application?
Can i use it as user control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible to embed unity exe (PC build) into WPF using WindowsFormsHost.
2. I'm not sure if it can be used as user control because the unity exe is completely separated from WPF application.

Comment: It's a little hacky, but you could try System.IO.Pipes to send information back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Few time ago, when I had to work with Unity 3d, there was a way to embed it into WebBrowser control.

See [this forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/10855-Unity-in-a-Window/page3) for more details.

Hope it can help you.