# Map rotation (skybox) XNA

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d, xna, skybox

I have a window form with xna included in a control, right now I have two models in one area of the screen. The thing is I need to rotate both models at the same time, I can rotate one object wich is a tank and the other is the skybox(landscape) rendered in a box.

The tank move with data provided by a serial port which is in real time, the tanks move perfectly, but I can't rotate the map.

(the ground should be moving along with the tank).

http://i61.tinypic.com/2efqrvc.jpg

I use this code to render the landscape:

```
private void SkyBoxRender()
    {
        RasterizerState originalRasterizerState = GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState;
        RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;

        aspectRatio = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
        orientacion = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(-85.0f), MathHelper.ToRadians(TiempoReal.rollPitch[1]), MathHelper.ToRadians(TiempoReal.rollPitch[0]));
        cameraPositionSkyBox = distance * new Vector3((float)Math.Sin(angle), 0, (float)Math.Cos(angle));

        foreach (EffectPass pass in skyBoxEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in skyBox.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
                {
                    part.Effect = skyBoxEffect;
                    part.Effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(Matrix.CreateScale(50.0f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(cameraPositionSkyBox));
                    part.Effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(view);
                    part.Effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f));
                    part.Effect.Parameters["SkyBoxTexture"].SetValue(skyBoxTexture);
                    part.Effect.Parameters["CameraPosition"].SetValue(cameraPositionSkyBox);
                }
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = originalRasterizerState;
    }
```

I think the problem is in the line part.Effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue.....
I don't know what to put there to make the map rotate using all the axis.

I rotate the tank using this code:

```
orientacion = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(-85.0f), 
              MathHelper.ToRadians(floatAngle1), MathHelper.ToRadians(floatAngle2));
```

If you look at the second line you can notice that I use angles to rotate the tank (it have to be in that way...), so any idea or suggestion?

Update:
Solved, how?

in the SkyBoxRender Method I added the following:

```
orientacionCamara = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(0.0f), MathHelper.ToRadians(floatAngle1), MathHelper.ToRadians(floatAngle2));
```

then I archived to move the camera in the map using this:
part.Effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(Matrix.CreateLookAt(yourCameraPosition) * orientacionCamara);

Now to move the camera at the same time with the same angles like the model I rotate the model, not the camera in this time.

```
private void BeginRender3D()
    {
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[modelo.Bones.Count];
        modelo.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        **orientacion** = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(-85.0f), MathHelper.ToRadians(floatAngle1), MathHelper.ToRadians(floatAngle2);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in modelo.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * **orientacion**;  //* orientacion
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camaraPosicion, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
        fps++;             
    }
```

I hope It can help to anyone, thanks for the suggestion guys.

Comment: sorry I don't see any caps, maybe my keyboard  configuration could be a problem for you? but I see all without caps.

Comment: ahh ok thanks for the advice, I am new here

Comment: This is not an answer, but a suggestion. [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) is no longer developed. I suggest moving to Unity which is currently thriving and out of the box takes care of many aspects of the game, e.g. skybox.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I know xna is no longer developed, but I have to work with a window form and the easiest way was trying to integrate one control render from xna... Does unity support windows forms? or I have to re-think all my program? thanks in advance

Comment: It seems possible. Quick google search confirms [that there are a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686050/unity3d-application-as-user-control)

Comment: So you basically don't want to rotate the object but the camera? Then you should adapt the view transform. In any case, you need to set a common matrix (be it the world matrix or the view matrix) for both objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could rotate the map by the orientation by multiplying the world parameter in the skyboxeffect by "orientacion". Still, you would have to make sure it rotates around the tanks position, by changing the whole line to this:

> `part.Effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(Matrix.CreateScale(50.0f) * matrix.createtranslation(TankPosition) * orientacion * Matrix.CreateTranslation(cameraPositionSkyBox - TankPosition));`

assuming "TankPosition" would be the position of your tank.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you're trying to simulate rotating a camera round the tank, I would just rotate the camera around the tank, by setting

> `view = matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView()`

Read up on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195667.aspx

Comment: thank you very much mate, you give me the light, now I updated the answer